# PHP: move_uploaded_file partially uploading

Tags: php

I am using the following code to upload a CSV to my server and process it. Occasionally (and very randomly), the file that is uploaded only contains half of the number of rows the original file contains (the original file contains 450 rows, but some of my uploads only contain ~200 rows). move_file_upload() is returning true, and this is happening before the CSV is processed. Any thoughts or ideas why? Yes, permissions are all correct.

```
// PHP:
public function import() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $destination = "./uploaded_csvs/reports/" . time()  . "_" . $this->request->data['Reports']['file']['name'];

        // Copy the report to the server
        if(move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Reports']['file']['tmp_name'], $destination)) {
            // Success - Process CSV
        } else {
            // Error
        }
    }
}

// HTML:
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ReportsForm" action="/Reports/import">
    <input type="file" id="ReportFile" size="7" value="" name="data[Report][file]">
    <input type="image" src="/img/buttons/save.png">
</form>
```

Comment: Check if any errors oncurred.

Comment: No, there were not any errors. Also, the file I am uploading is 54kb total (so size isn't an issue).

Comment: If move_uploaded_file returns true, then there was nothing wrong with the upload.  The only possibility I can think of is that your local file was half way through being written to by another process when you clicked on the save button.

Answer (score 1):

`move_upload_file` will NOT truncate a file. It'll simply move whatever was uploaded. If the file's coming out short, then that's what the server received.

The very FIRST thing you should ALWAYS do with an upload is verify that it [actually succeeded](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die('Upload failed with error code #' . $_FILES['file']['error']);
}
```

Never assume success. Always check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.